# Changing page title without java/jquery

Tags: php, html, seo, title

so my index page looks like this

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>
 <main id="main" role="main">
   <?php
    if ($_GET['page'] == "") {
        if ($_POST['page'] <> "") {
            $page = $_POST['page'];
            }
        else {
            $page = "homepage";
            }
        }
    else {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        }

    switch($page) {
    case "about": include "about.php"; break;
    case "mission": include "mission.php"; break;
    ?>
  </main>
 <?php include 'footer.php';?>
```

The header got a standard title tag, my question is how can i change the title for each index.php?page=page-name

Comment: Move your 'page' detection logic in header.php before the title tag!?

Comment: that would be *javaSCRIPT*

Answer (score 0):

By the time your page check has started, `header.php` has already been interpreted. So there is no way to inject the title unless you put the page check above the title.

Additionally, since you're checking both `GET` and `POST`, you might consider simplifying your code as follows:

```
<?php

switch($_REQUEST['page']) {
    case "about":
        include "about.php";
        break;

    case "mission":
        include "mission.php";
        break;

    default:
        include "homepage.php";
}
```

Comment: i found one way to add between title tags <?php echo $_GET["page"];?>

Comment: @FarcasAlexandru that is dangerous, because you're not validating the user input against a white list of known safe values.

Comment: so @mistermartin whats your suggestions to make everything work well and to be able for seo

Comment: After i used your code now i get a php error that says Notice: Undefined index: page in